# Chemicals sprayed on balcony concerned its harmful to my cat

Tags: animals

I live in a 2nd floor apartment and I let my cat lounge on the balcony. I have had an insect infestation on the balcony that I treated with a permethrin spray.

It's been 8 hrs since I sprayed the balcony and now I'm concerned whether to let my cat out. Is it safe, or if not, how can I clean my balcony so it is safe for the cat and so that washing it does not endanger other animals.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not possible to judge this without knowing the exact dosage and related information. Don't trust your cat's life on the opinion of a random stranger on the internet.

Comment: This question can be answered even without more data.  Permethrin can be very toxic to cats, and this fact needs to be emphasized..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about The Great Outdoors.  It may be welcome on [Pets.SE].

Comment: Useful question, but belongs on pets.se. OP, more practically, check the labels on the product you used, and possibly call and ask the manufacturer. If you are concerned, don't risk it.

Answer (score 3):

See [International Cat Care](https://icatcare.org/advice/permethrin-poisoning/).  **I agree with Separatrix that the balcony probably needs to be scrbbed down before you let your cat on it.** If it were my cat, I'd consult my vet, bringing the bottle with me, and describing how much I used.

**I doubt that rain will do a good enough job.** Permethrin is oil based, and according to [this reference](https://www.google.com/search?q=regal+dulles&oq=Regal+Dulles&aqs=chrome.0.0l8.4202j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) can persist outdoors for days.

The [National Pesticide Information Center](http://npic.orst.edu/factsheets/PermGen.html) discusses how to clean a permethrin sprayed surface, **but you need to call their number (given at the bottom of the article) or visit your vet.**

Answer (score 2):

Permethrin in high concentrations is harmful to cats. In low concentrations it's used as a flea treatment, including for cats.

What you've used was probably a relatively high concentration since it wasn't used for flea treatment on an animal. You might want to wash the balcony down or wait until it's rained before letting the cat out. It's reasonable to be concerned.